# syntax error unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am a  beginner in PHP and MySQL and don't know what's wrong. It says error on line 8:

```
syntax error unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING)
```

Here is the code:

```html
<?php
require "conn.php";

$category = $_POST["category"];
$fruit = $_POST["fruit"];
$cost = $_POST["cost"];

DELETE FROM `Temptable` WHERE image_path = "";
UPDATE Temptable SET (`category`, `fruit`, `cost`) VALUES ('$category','$fruit','$cost');
$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO Datatable (`category`, `fruit`, `cost`) SELECT `categrory`, `fruit`, `cost` FROM `Temptable` WHERE `id` >= '1'";

if($Datatable->query($mysql_qry) === true) {
 echo "Successful";
}
else {
 echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $Datatable->error;
}
$Datatable->close();
$Temptable->close();
?>
```

Comment: I mean... What are you expecting? PHP != SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is being generated simply because you have put mysql queries directly into PHP code which PHP is unable to understand. You should put `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements as string variable like you did for the `INSERT` statement

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$category = $_POST["category"];
$fruit = $_POST["fruit"];
$cost = $_POST["cost"];

$delete_query = "DELETE FROM `Temptable` WHERE image_path = ''";
$update_query = "UPDATE Temptable SET (`category`, `fruit`, `cost`) VALUES ('$category','$fruit','$cost')";
$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO Datatable (`category`, `fruit`, `cost`) SELECT `categrory`, `fruit`, `cost` FROM `Temptable` WHERE `id` >= '1'";

if($Datatable->query($mysql_qry) === true) {
    echo "Successful";
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $Datatable->error;
}

$Datatable->close();
$Temptable->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` and `update` statements need to be commented out or created correctly as variables - you were getting an error because of those strings

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";

    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $fruit = $_POST["fruit"];
    $cost = $_POST["cost"];

    #DELETE FROM `Temptable` WHERE image_path = "";
    #UPDATE Temptable SET (`category`, `fruit`, `cost`) VALUES ('$category','$fruit','$cost');
    $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO Datatable (`category`, `fruit`, `cost`) SELECT `categrory`, `fruit`, `cost` FROM `Temptable` WHERE `id` >= '1'";

    if($Datatable->query($mysql_qry) === true) {
        echo "Successful";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $Datatable->error;
    }
    $Datatable->close();
    $Temptable->close();
?>
```